# Where do I begin with this jQuery/WordPress error? Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Where do I begin with this jQuery error? Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined

The error:

```
:formatted:55 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined
    at n (:formatted:55)
    at :formatted:125
    at dispatch (??/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js,/wp-content/js/postmessage.js?m=1377267974j:3)
    at r.handle (??/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js,/wp-content/js/postmessage.js?m=1377267974j:3)
```

The context:

```
if ("string" != typeof n.apiVersion && (n.apiVersion = "1",
n.version && (n.apiVersion = n.version.replace(/[^0-9\.]/, ""))),

// this is the line where the error occurs
r = window.location.protocol + "//public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v" + n.apiVersion + n.path + (-1 === n.path.indexOf("?") ? "?" : "&") + "http_envelope=1",

n.apiNamespace && (r = window.location.protocol + "//public-api.wordpress.com/" + n.apiNamespace + n.path + (-1 === n.path.indexOf("?") ? "?" : "&") + "_envelope=1"),
n.query && ("string" == typeof n.query ? r += "&" + n.query.replace(/^&/, "") : r += "&" + jQuery.param(n.query)),
s = n.supports_args,
```

Looking at the stacktrace, it looks as though this is related to jQuery or WordPress's version of jQuery, perhaps. I don't really see anything that indicates a location within my own code. How am I going to find out what's causing this? Looking at the stacktrace, I wasn't really able to determine where the error might have originated. The error occurs on page load.

It seems this might be the WordPress version of jQuery, I'm not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: I know this is a _hacky_ way of going about it, I usually try the process of elimination when I'm having trouble determining the source of the error.  That is, I begin by commenting out what I believe to be the offending code.  Once I've tracked down specific code that caused the error, then I proceed from there in finding a solution.  I know this doesn't answer your question but it's a place to start when I'm stuck.

Comment: well path appears to be undefined so figure out why it is undefined

Comment: check if n is defined before you use it. if n is ok, then check n.path. If both are ok then you have no indexOf property for n.path.

Answer (score 0):

This actually ended up being a caching issue, I believe. I opened an incognito window, saw the error was gone, then cleared my browser's cache.

The code in the stacktrace didn't have any of my own code in it, so I thought that was weird. Clearing the cache fixed it.